# Error: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel

Tags: fakedb

I've recently imported a couple of the Test projects from a site running Sitecore 8.2 into a site running 7.2.  When I run the tests, they all error with the message

> Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel.

In `app.config`, I found this:

```
<!-- DATABASE TYPE
     For Sitecore versions prior to 8.2 should be 'Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel'.
     For Sitecore 8.2 and later should be 'Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel'. -->
<sc.variable name="databaseType" value="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

So I replaced all instances in the solution of `Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase` with `Sitecore.Data.Database`, but I still get the same error.

The test projects are using FakeDb.

Comment: Matt - did you copy the whole test project into your 7.2 implementation, or setup a new one and copy in the test code? Make sure that you don't have a patch file like the one that @Mark mentioned that is overriding that class name.

Comment: I copied the whole project and then changed the configuration and Nuget references to work for 7.2. I have the mentioned patch file, but I've changed the values to Sitecore.Data.Database.  Perhaps I should just remove the patch altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a couple of the patch files hanging around on the file system.  They weren't in the solution, so I didn't spot them at first until I did a search through the file system for "Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase".

Now I have a whole new unrelated error to work through.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore 8.2 introduced changes to the way `Database` is handled internally. To make FakeDB work on 8.2, you need to add a configuration snippet to `App_Config\Include` containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <databases>
      <database id="core">
        <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel</patch:attribute>
      </database>
      <database id="master">
        <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel</patch:attribute>
      </database>
      <database id="web">
        <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel</patch:attribute>
      </database>
    </databases>
    <!-- EVENTING -->
    <eventing defaultProvider="sitecore">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" systemDatabaseName="core" />
      </providers>
    </eventing>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

More information to be found here: [Sitecore 8.2 - Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.Database. No matching constructor was found.](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/issues/139)

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to work the other way around, ie; my solution is for a Sitecore 7.2 site.

Comment: In which case the solution would be the opposite. You can assume it's patched like I describe here; find that patch and remove it.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried removing that patch, and still the same thing.  There's literally no reference to the string "Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase" anywhere in the solution.  I'm wondering if some of the other assemblies like Autofixture might be using too new a version which specifically expects Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase.  Perhaps downgrading them may work.